# Telerik Reference in Installshield

Tags: winforms, telerik, setup-deployment, installshield-le

I am creating setup through installshield in vs 2012. When running the setup at client side then throwing below error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Aqua, Version=2013.3.1016.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5bb2a467cbec794e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Anybody can help to sort out the issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to include that file 'Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Aqua' in your InstallShield installer.  I am not sure based on what you asked if that you are directly referencing that dll or that one of your other Telerik controls is implicitly referencing.

Any reference that you have in your projects references must be included in your installer.  Those dll's may also have implicit references that will not show up in your References.  Usually in the help documentation of most 3rd party vendor controls is a section about deployment to clients.  They will usually list what are the implicit references of what to include with your project.

Comment: I ended up my issue to follow the given [Telerik link][1],
I Changed to "True" reference property "Copy local", it automatically copied to "debug" folder. When I ready to setup, I just included folder with Telerik DLLs and it distributed on client machines successfully.

Comment: This method of distribution is against the Telerik's license agreement. Here you can find what are the appropriate way to distribute applications using Telerik UI for WinForms controls: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/installation-deployment-and-distribution-redestributing-telerik-radcontrols-for-windows.html